# How to use LINKAGE SECTION and WORKING-STORAGE SECTION in the same file?

Tags: cobol

I'm trying to write a COBOL module and having some variables in this file too:

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. UTIL.

   DATA DIVISION.
   LINKAGE SECTION.
   01 MY_VAR PIC X(100).

   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 RESULT PIC X(200) value SPACES.

   PROCEDURE DIVISION USING MY_VAR.
       STRING INPUT DELIMITED BY SPACE
              ' '   DELIMITED BY SIZE
              MY_VAR BY SPACE
       INTO RESULT
       DISPLAY RESULT
   EXIT PROGRAM.
```

For the input argument (`MY_VAR`) I use `LINKAGE SECTION`. I'm not sure how to use the `WORKING-STORAGE SECTION` statement to declare the `RESULT` variable.

How can I do that?

Comment: Yes, there are up to four DIVISIONs, which, if used, must be unique per program. Then there are SECTIONs. For those that are not user-named, ie anything before the PROCEDURE DIVISION header, the order is important. OK, relevant to a program compiling.

Comment: @BillWoodger True. Thanks a lot. I wrote a tiny COBOL module to execute [JS/Node.js in COBOL](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/node.cobol). :D

Comment: @IonicăBizău http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cobol/cobol_program_structure.htm Has some information on some of the sections in the divisions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have 1 Data Division. Also, I think the order is not good for the Sections. 
I advise looking at some Cobol documentation before coding.

```
     IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. UTIL.

   DATA DIVISION.

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 RESULT PIC X(200) value SPACES.

   LINKAGE SECTION.
   01 MY_VAR PIC X(100).



   PROCEDURE DIVISION USING MY_VAR.
       STRING INPUT DELIMITED BY SPACE
              ' '   DELIMITED BY SIZE
              MY_VAR BY SPACE
       INTO RESULT
       DISPLAY RESULT
   EXIT PROGRAM.
```

Comment: I tried something similar, but I didn't know the order is important. :-)

Comment: I just saw the article on Ars Technica and relized that I saw your name somewhere these days. Felicitari din Bucuresti!

Comment: Oh, thanks! :D Don't tell me you're a COBOL developer! Salutări din Bihor :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Cobol program on the mainframe of PC? If on PC - which Cobol program are you using?
If you are using a linkage section, first 2 bytes specify the length of the variable.
Also - I don't see the definition of the INPUT variable, unless INPUT is some kind of Cobol command (not recognized on the mainframe computers).

The correct syntax (on the mainframe) is:

```
LINKAGE SECTION.
   01 link-parms.
      05 LNK-PARM-LENGTH         PIC S9999 COMP. 
      05 MY_VAR PIC X(100). 

   PROCEDURE DIVISION USING MY_VAR.
       STRING INPUT DELIMITED BY SPACE
              ' '   DELIMITED BY SIZE
              MY_VAR BY SPACE
       INTO RESULT
       DISPLAY RESULT
       STOP RUN.
```

Comment: You are correct about the `INPUT`, incorrect about the length of a field. That (on the Mainframe) is only true for the program initiated by z/OS with the `EXEC PGM=...` where any value on the `PARM` is available in the LINKAGE SECTION as you then describe. It is not true for any other LINKAGE SECTION item, unless documented that way.